# Asset Pipeline and Images stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1 application where user-uploaded images are stored in the database.  I'm using a dedicated path to serve these images through a Rails controller.  Here is a portion of my routes.rb:

```
get "images/book_covers/:book_id", :controller => :book_covers, :action => :show
get "assets/book_covers/:book_id", :controller => :book_covers, :action => :show
```

Here is the code from the controller:

```
class BookCoversController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if @image = BookCover.find_by_book_id(params[:book_id])
      send_data(@image.image, :type => @image.content_type, :filename => "book_cover_#{@image.book_id}", :disposition => 'inline')
    else
      render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

This all works wonderfully in development mode (since asset pipelining is disabled), but when I try the app in production, I get (predictably, I suppose) the error: "ActionView::Template::Error (book_covers/61 isn't precompiled)".  Here is the code that renders the image:

```
<%= image_tag book[:cover_image], :class => book[:cover_source].downcase %>
```

I'd rather not disable asset pipelining for the entire app, just for these images.  How can I accomplish this (or am I just approaching this whole issue wrong)?

Comment: You use some assets_host configuration ?

Comment: What return exactly the `book[:cover_image]` ?

Comment: @shingara I am using the default assets_host configuration - in fact I have not customized any of the asset configuration values.  book[:cover_image] returns a relative path (such as "book_covers/1" which the BookCoversController then handles).

Comment: I don't think the asset pipeline serves any purpose if you are pulling data from a DB. Serve them using a controller per @Wolfgang and keep them out of /assets. You can also write them into /public in the controller action so they'll be served on future requests by the web server.

Answer (score 3):

How about generating the image tag yourself without the asset pipeline, i.e. first name the route:

```
get "images/book_covers/:book_id", :controller => :book_covers, :action => :show, :as => :book_cover_image
```

and then in the template

```
<%= tag :img, :src => book_cover_image_path( book[:id], :class => book[:cover_source].downcase ) %>
```

Now the asset pipeline won't even know about your image, and your controller's show action will be called with the book's id as parameter.